# How to make an extremely simple operating system?

Tags: raspberry-pi, google-glass

I have a project to do that requires making an operating system. Our aim is to make our own version of Google Glass. The glasses part is easy and we plan to use a Raspberry Pi for the system. However we are not sure how to make an incredibly simple operating system like the one for Google Glass with minimal mouse movements to operate it. Someone please help?

Comment: that's the most interesting question I've seen since months!!! :) +1 Can you explain *why* do you need a custom operating system for that? can't you use raspbian or android?

Comment: It took more than 20 years to create Linux as it is today. Google Glass is running Linux - so it is not exactly very simple OS. Do you really expect that you can create one as small side project?

Comment: Snatch the smallest linux distro that you can find (I can think of DSL but there are many), strip it down to the bare minimum you need, profit

Comment: @Alex Or follow the LFS instructions to make a bare minimum distro...

Answer (score 3):

Wow sounds like a cool project. Instead of creating the operating system yourself how about just creating a SHELL.

Which means that you would be using some OS of your choice to Handel all the low level hardware stuff and you shell would tell the Pi what to do and how to do it.

A shell uses a read–eval–print loop (REPL) which is: a simple, interactive computer programming environment. see [WIKIPEDIA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) for more info

I think that would be easier than creating a OS.

If you still wnat to make your own OS then take a look at these links:

[PINTOS](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/10wi-cs140/pintos/pintos.html)
[Rasberry Pi - OS HOw To](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=720)

I hope i could help.

Best of luck

Comment: OK but why are u tying to reinvent the wheel. An OS is one of the most complicated piece of software you can write.

Comment: what does a small interface and minimal mouse movement have to do with the type and size of the operating system?  you are not making those connections clear.  you have plenty to do just getting the hardware and application working than to worry about the operating system.

Comment: I think you either have a different definition of an OS or you're heavily underestimating the complexity of an OS. Even when we're not (like the commenters above) talking about the graphical layer that sits all the way at the top you have to worry about hardware abstraction, drivers, bootstrapping, scheduling, interrupts, queuing, messaging and a million other things that you have not even heard about. To give you an idea: the Linux _kernel_ has about 15M lines of code.

Comment: Sure, a small OS can be done, we did them in less than 16KB of memory. Still a multi-person multi-year project. Judging from your comments you need to get someone on your team that knows what an OS is and has been a developer on one. As said above, the best bet is to start with a stripped-down Linux kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Better make it under CreativeCommons....You can still make money through donations -- sure it sounds like you (You's') wanna get rich on something that isacopy of someone elses work and a big co.. no good!

Most important thing isto have atotally different Kernell from Linux, like they distanced themselves from Windows